# Run Python script with Google Cloud Scheduler?

Tags: python, cron, scheduler

I currently have a couple of Python files with 1 file as the entry point, and want to run it every 12 hours. I'm open to trying any online cronjob service, but cannot figure out what to input for a target/HTTP URL/etc when setting up a job with Google Cloud Scheduler, cron-job.org, or any other service. How do I set up a URL as a target that runs the Python script?

Comment: You could use the [Crono API](https://www.crono.com/#api) and specify the URL that way:
`"task": {
    "type": "request",
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "{url}"
  }`
Feel free to reach out for more details and to request a token.

Comment: I don't quite understand where a URL comes from to begin with, though - is that where the scripts are hosted?

Comment: Ah, I see. You will need to _expose_ your Python file/function to the web so you can reference it in your cron job. To do so, you can use a web framework such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in Python.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you!